Script moves directory instead of re-naming it according to specified rules
I hacked a script that's supposed to remove all double-digit integer or decimal numbers (including the decimal) from the directory name of the parent and all its subfolders recursively.
Examples:

integer (11,00,02)
decimal (11.25, 11.01)

Before:
20-29\ Abstract\ Social\ Ltd.
After:
Abstract\ Social\ Ltd.
However, there are some bugs in it that I was unable to fix. When ran with main folder as argument, it throws below error. The directory in question seems to be moved to its parent.
./remove_johnny_decimals.sh /Volumes/Files/Files/20-29\ Abstract\ Social\ Ltd.

/Volumes/Files/Files/20-29 Abstract Social Ltd./21 Finance -> /Volumes/Files/Files/21 Finance
iterate_folders:2: no matches found: /Volumes/Files/Files/20-29 Abstract Social Ltd./21 Finance/*

Here's the current version of the script:
#!/bin/zsh

# Define the function to remove Johnny Decimals
remove_johnny_decimal() {
    local folder="$1"
    local new_folder="${folder%%[0-9]*}$(basename "$folder")"
    if [[ "$folder" != "$new_folder" ]]; then
        mv -v "$folder" "$new_folder"
    fi
}

# Main function to iterate through folders recursively
iterate_folders() {
    local dir="$1"
    for folder in "$dir"/*; do
        if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
            remove_johnny_decimal "$folder"
            iterate_folders "$folder"
        fi
    done
}

# Check if the main folder path is provided as an argument
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <main_folder_path>"
    exit 1
fi

main_folder="$1"

# Check if the main folder exists
if [[ ! -d "$main_folder" ]]; then
    echo "Error: Main folder not found: $main_folder"
    exit 1
fi

# Start iterating from the specified main folder
iterate_folders "$main_folder"

I'm open to a completely different way to accomplish what I'm looking!

Could it be that $new_folder already exists? I don't see that you would check this.

${folder%%[0-9]*} is going to remove a digit followed by anything, so if folder is set to 20-29 Abstract Social Ltd., it will expand to an empty string.

Didn't quite follow your renaming requirement. Do you only want to remove double-digit numbers, but not single digits or triple digits? Do you want to keep the decimal point in numbers like 11.01? A list of before-and-after folder names would be helpful.

zsh tip: "$dir"/*(/) will expand to only directories, so you can leave out the later explicit check. Look up "glob qualifiers" in the documentation for more.

Try this:
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

get_updated_name() {
    local name=${1:?}
    name=${name//[[:digit:]][[:digit:].,-]#[[:digit:]]}
    name=${name//[[:space:]]##/ }
    name=${${name# }% }
    print -r -- $name
}
local base_dir=${1:?Base folder name is required}
autoload zmv
zmv -iv $base_dir'/(*/)##(#qod)' '${f:h}/$(get_updated_name ${f:t})/' 

This uses zsh's recursive glob to traverse the directory tree, and the zmv utility to rename the directories. Some of the pieces:

get_updated_names - this function will take a directory name as a parameter, and print an updated name to stdout. The updates:

name=${name//[[:digit:]][[:digit:].,-]#[[:digit:]]} - removes sequences from the name that start and end with a digit, and have zero or more digits, dots, commas, or dashes in between. It uses the ${//} substitution, replacing the input pattern with an empty string. Some examples:

3 - not removed
33 - removed
33.3, 44-44, 55,66,77, 5,6,7 - all are removed
5~6~7 - not removed


name=${name//[[:space:]]##/ } - normalize spaces. Removing the numbers above could leave some adjacent spaces in the filename. This will change all sequences of various whitespace characters to a single space, including those in directory names that might not otherwise be altered.
Note that this pattern and the prior pattern require that extendedglob be set - that's being automatically done by zmv here.
name=${${name# }% } - remove a leading space or a trailing space if needed.


autoload zmv - zmv is included with the zsh distribution, but it's only available when requested; autoload is used to make that request.
zmv ... - zmv is a very versatile bulk-renaming utility. It will check for unaltered filenames, naming collisions, and can be set to confirm each change.

-i - interactive; ask if each directory should be renamed. This is a way to test if the patterns do what is expected.
-v - verbose.
$base_dir'/(*/)##(#qod)' - input pattern for zmv. In this form, the recursive glob will  generate a list of directories underneath the base directory. With the (#qod) glob qualifier, the list will be sorted with subdirectories first, so that we can change the lower-level names first.
Changing subdirectories first is required - otherwise we would try to rename those subdirectories using the prior base name, which no longer exists.
'${f:h}/$(get_updated_name ${f:t})/' - output pattern. In zmv, $f is the filename from the input pattern, so ${f:h} is the dirname, and ${f:t} is the basename. get_updated_name is used to build the new base name.



Changes needed to meet any other renaming requirements can go in the get_updated_name function.
